# Regex Not Match To Next Line

Tags: .net, regex

Want to match what is after "subject" or "subject:" but only on that line
I want to search all lines for subject or subject:
But if the rest of the line is blank not match

```
(?i)(?<=\bSubject:?\s+).+$
```

Sample text

```
Subject:  
Pat Sanders
```

(line break between Subject: and Pat)

That regex is matching Pat Sanders.
Since it is on the next line I do NOT want it to match.

The regex is compiled with `RegexOptions.Multiline`

I think the `.+` is greedy and consuming the line break.

This works in that it only matches on the current line:

```
(?i)(?<=\bsubject:).+?$
```

But this does not work:

```
(?i)(?<=\bsubject:?).+?$
```

The lookback does not consume the :
The : is included in the match

Answer (score 0):

try this may work

```
(\b(subject)\b).+(?=\s+\r?$)
```

Comment: I already tied that.  It has the effect of the line break is not part of the match but it still matches to Pat Sanders.  It just does not have a line break before Pat Sanders.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Subject:[\w ]+$
```

See it here: http://rubular.com/r/k8SyIO6c2R

Comment: That will match on "subject:"  and I don't want it to.  Subject is a forward look around.